# Dynamic inputs not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

The issue i have here is that when i try to add rows the function doesnt seem to work the button 'add row' is doing nothing. I am trying to capture values and give them names like item1[] price1[]...
I need to capture and call the values with php since i am very new to javascript i cant really write my code only in jscript.

```js
function addRow(tableID,ID1,ID2,ID3) {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var table1 = document.getElementById(ID1).id;
        var table2 = document.getElementById(ID2).id;
        var table3 = document.getElementById(ID3).id;

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var x = document.getElementById(tableID).id;
  
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "checkbox";
        element1.name="chkbox[]";
        cell1.appendChild(element1);

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name="+table1+" id="+table1+"/>";

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        cell3.innerHTML = "<input type='text'  name="+table2+" id="+table2+"/>";

        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        cell4.innerHTML =  "<input type='text'  name="+table3+" id="+table3+"/>";

  }
    function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try { 
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }
        }
        }catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
        <meta name="Author" content="" /> 
        <meta name="Keywords" content="Programmation,Web,PHP,MySQL,MariaDB" /> 
        <meta name="Description" content="" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />  
    </head> 
    <body>  
<HEAD>
 <TITLE> Add/Remove dynamic rows in HTML table </TITLE>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <SCRIPT language="javascript">
<?php
    $groups = 5; //number of groups
    $rows = 3; //number of rows per group
$arr = array('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday');
$arr1 = array(
array(1,2,3),
array(4,5,6),
array(7,8,9),
array(10,11,12),
array(13,14,15)
);
$arr2= array('soup','maindish','dessert');

 for( $g = 0; $g < $groups; ++$g )
        {
   
?>
   <table id='<?php echo $g; ?>'>
   <thead>
            <tr>  
                <caption><?php echo $arr[$g]; ?></caption>
            </tr>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th width="94">Item</th>
<th width="121">Price</th>
<th width="84">Qty</th>
</thead>
<?php
            for( $r=0; $r < $rows; ++$r )
            {
    ?>
<form action='tablebuilder.php' method='post'>
<tbody id="datatable<?php echo $arr1[$g][$r]; ?>">
<tr>
 <th rowspan="1000"><?php echo $arr2[$r];?></th> 
 <td><input type='checkbox'></td>
 <td><input type='text' name='item<?php echo $arr1[$g][$r];?>[]' id='item<?php echo $arr1[$g][$r];?>[]'></td> 
 <td><input type='text' name='price<?php echo $arr1[$g][$r]; ?>[]' id='price<?php echo $arr1[$g][$r]; ?>[]'></td>
 <td><input type='text' name='qty<?php echo $arr1[$g][$r]; ?>[]' id='qty<?php echo $arr1[$g][$r]; ?>[]'></td>
 <td><input type="button" value="AddRow" Onclick="addRow('datatable<?php echo $arr1[$g][$r]; ?>','item<?php echo $arr1[$g][$r];?>[]','price<?php echo $arr1[$g][$r]; ?>[]','qty<?php echo $arr1[$g][$r]; ?>[]')"/></td>
 <td><input type="button" value="DeleteRow" Onclick="deleteRow('datatable<?php echo $arr1[$g][$r];?>')"/></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
 
<?php
   }
        }
?> 
 </table>
 <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'/>
  </form>
<?php  
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo $_POST['qty1'][1];
} 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The html/php code i am using here is to create 5 tables with 3 rows each row being respectively soup,main dish and dessert.

Comment: *"the button 'add row' is doing nothing*" Have you checked your browser console for errors while trying to run your `javascript` function(s)?

Comment: It is not working because JohnDoe have added .id

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) demonstrating the problem. The snippets you've created aren't runnable. Pay attention to the labels on the boxes in the editor UI, and the buttons down the side, and ensure that the problem is replicated when you click **Run code snippet**.

Answer (score 1):

Remove .id from your code on following lines.

```
 table1 = document.getElementById(ID1).id;
        var table2 = document.getElementById(ID2).id;
        var table3 = document.getElementById(ID3).id;
var x = document.getElementById(tableID).id;
```

and make it

```
  table1 = document.getElementById(ID1);
            var table2 = document.getElementById(ID2);
            var table3 = document.getElementById(ID3);
    var x = document.getElementById(tableID);
```

Comment: I tried removing the .id already and the 'add row' button starts working again. But once i test to see if i can capture any values of the additional inputs i created with echo $_POST['price1'][1]; nothing happens. Only the first value is captured echo $_POST['price1'][0];

Comment: I posted the full code in the snippet i will try to edit it in the main thread to make it run. But idk why the snippet isnt reading the php part of the code...

Comment: @JohnDoe: ...and more to the point, questions must be self-contained, rather than relying on off-site content.

Comment: Link should be working actually... i will try to edit the code in the main thread. I made some modifications but it still doesnt work.

Comment: I edited the code. And added ids to the form the add rows button works but i still fail to capture the values once they are called with php.